# django wagtail bootstraping cms features and a CRUD API

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, wagtail

What I am trying to achieve.

1. Create user for closed user group through API
2. Wagatail admin logs in and see's all pending users in a panel similar to that provided by wagatil for wagtail users
3. Accept user or deny user by checking a box.

Background

I have need for a closed user group. This user group will have the following fields.

First name,
Last Name,
Email,
PAssword,
Status.

I would like to use the Wagatil API V2 to be able to create a user with the given fields but based on the [doc](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/advanced_topics/api/v2/usage.html#images) the rest API V2 is only based on retrieving data ?

Secondly I'm trying to bootstap Wagtail CMS features.

The closed user group differ from the users I create for wagtail (settings/users). I do not want these users to be wagtail admins.

However I would like my Wagtail admins to manage them with similar ease that wagtail provides for their users from the settings/users panel.

Can I use the same features wagtail provides internally for their users to my closed user group from my cms panel?

What I have managed to come across is to customize CMS  [templates](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html). This doesn't provide me what I want as I would like a feature in the menu that says manage closed user group and it would appear similar to the one internally provided by wagtail.

How do I create the CRUD api using their tools and how do I create a plugin for the CMS based on their "user cms plugin"?

Comment: The general approach would be to write the functionality you need using regular Django views, and then integrate them into the Wagtail admin (e.g. adding menu items, and URL routes within /admin) using hooks: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html